# Ubuntu 18.04 with dedicated GPU + eGPU?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, gpu

With the following hardware:

Settings > Details > About

```
Processor Intel Core i7-7700HQ CPU
Graphics GeForce GTX 1070 with MaxQ Design/PCIe/SSE2
GNOME 3.28.2
OS type 64 bit
```

Software & Updates > Additional Drivers

```
NVIDIA Corporation: GP104M [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile] (GeForce GTX 1070 Max-Q)
[x] Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-415 (open-source)
[ ] Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-396 (open-source)
[ ] Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-410 (open-source)
[ ] Using X. Org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)
```

I plugged in, via thunderbolt 3, an eGPU and booted my device. However the eGPU is not detected.

Any thoughts?

[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036271/ubuntu-18-04-egpu-not-work) didn't help me any...

Comment: What laptop is this ?
What type is EGPU?
dmsg may be ?

Comment: @DimitarAtanasov just a generic laptop. also a nvidia gpu in an akito enclosure.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/56427/external-gpu-system-in-linux/1207904#1207904  and search this site for egpu.  I never had to mess with xorg.conf for my gtx970 plugged into an expresscard slot, ubuntu supplied drivers just worked, and no particular issues, but see the egpu.io site for builds similar to yours.